# In GIT can we combine commit pointers in this way?

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit

In the following diagram (taken from http://schacon.github.io/git/git-rev-parse#_specifying_revisions), can E not also be referenced by this pointer:

**A~^2**

```
G   H   I   J
 \ /     \ /
  D   E   F
   \  |  / \
    \ | /   |
     \|/    |
      B     C
       \   /
        \ /
         A
A =      = A^0
B = A^   = A^1     = A~1
C = A^2  = A^2
D = A^^  = A^1^1   = A~2
E = B^2  = A^^2
F = B^3  = A^^3
G = A^^^ = A^1^1^1 = A~3
H = D^2  = B^^2    = A^^^2  = A~2^2
I = F^   = B^3^    = A^^3^
J = F^2  = B^3^2   = A^^3^2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A~`, which is `A~1`, refers to `B`, and `B^2` refers to `E`, so if I correctly parsed your question — you have asked whether `E` can also be referred to using the refspec `A~^2`, — the answer is "yes, it can be".

Comment: Yes that was my question. So I guess the diagram is not meant to show every possible way to reference something but to show how the pointers work in general.

Comment: @AndyCribbens, given that `~<n>` means "apply `^1` `<n>` times", then quite possibly yes. IOW, the `~` operator is somewhat redundant, but if it were not implemented, one would need to use long sequences of `^`s instead, which is not too convenient.

Comment: @AndyCribbens, JFTR I'd possibly give a hint at why `~` is even needed. The thing is, while Git supports different workflows, its [main one](https://hackernoon.com/how-the-creators-of-git-do-branches-e6fcc57270fb) and the most widely used other workflows give special meaning to "the main line of development" in the sense all development happens on branches which are forked off some branch and then get merged back into it. Due to this, it's sometimes useful to consider just the history of such "mainline" branch ignoring what was committed on those "temporary" branches…

Comment: @AndyCribbens, `~` supports this workflow, and, say, `git log` has the "--first-parent" command-line option which also only traverses the chain of "left parents" of merge commits only.